# How to change the display of a text UI by adding 1

Tags: c#

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text scoreText;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        scoreText.text = +1;
    }
}
```

Sorry i'm very new at c-sharp and couldn't figure it out. It comes up with the error 'cannot implicitly convert type  'int' to 'string'.

Comment: hi Dan, can you confirm if one of the answers below helped out, if yes, you can click on the green tickbox to mark as resolved . Cheers !!

Answer (score 1):

`scoreText.Text` is of type `string` and your assigning type `int`

```
int number = 1;
scoreText.text = number++.ToString();
```

Comment: This is the better solution IMHO.

Comment: @John, OP is trying to increment previous value of `scoreText.text`. correct me if I am wrong, this code will assign 2 everytime buecause value of `number` will be 1 everytime

Comment: @Prasad Yes, but if OP declares `number` in a sensible place, rather than in the `OnTriggerEnter2D` method, then this is definitely better than constantly converting string->int->string.

Answer (score 1):

change to this:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    scoreText.text  = (Convert.ToInt32(scoreText.text) + 1).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you neet to convert `scoreText.text` to integer becauses type of `scoreText.text` string. Then increment it by one and convert again to string and assign it back to `scoreText.text`

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    //Convert scoreText.text to integer.
    int previousValue = Convert.ToInt32(scoreText.text);
    //Increment it by one, convert to string and assign it to scoreText.text
    scoreText.text = (previousValue++).ToString();
}
```